# iptables "invalid port/service" returned when trying to do multiple ports

Tags: iptables

I am attempting to create the following IP table but I have issues when trying to set multiple ports in this case 80 & 110 I can't figure out how to set multiple ports in the same rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80,110 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2
```

The following error is returned

```
iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): invalid port/service `80,110' specified
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
man iptables-extensions

       -m multiport

       [!] --destination-ports,--dports port[,port|,port:port]...
              Match if the destination port is one of the given ports.  The flag --dports
 is a convenient alias for this option.
```

So it must be:

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,110 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2`

(not tested I've long switched to nftables).